# Which files should be checked in to SVN from Visual Studio Project Files in C#/VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, version-control

I find [this](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_File_Extensions) page very useful in distinguishing which files should be checked in to the Version Control System in Delphi. Is there a similar page that shows which files in VB.Net should be checked in to the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [Ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), I didn't have to worry on which files to be checked in because this tool knows it all.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend (from bitter experience) not checking in

- SUO files (a users personal solution option files)
- USER files ( a users personal project file settings)
- The Bin folder and it's contents
- The obj folder and its contents

Hope this helps

Comment: If I'm also building an installer for those exes/dlls, I +DO+ check in the EXE/DLL (ie at least some of the contents of the BIN folder) since, in effect, those files then become "source code" for the installer build process...

Answer (score 2):

- Put the solution file (.sln) into VCS.
- Put all the files in the “My Project” folder into VCS.
- From the main directory for your project:

  - Add the source code files. You will have explicitly created these files, with the extensions .vb, storing classes, forms and modules. In WinForms each form will have three corresponding files that must be added to VCS: “.designer.vb”, “.resx” and “.vb”.
  - You may also need to add other files with different extensions if you have created database connections etc.
  - Add the general files from the main project directory “app.config”, “ApplicationEvents.vb”, “Project.vbproj” and “Project.vbproj.user”.
- In general don’t add any files from the obj or bin directory. These folders store built exes and intermediate files created by the compiler. You might want to keep the built EXE or DLL files in VCS, depending on personal preference.

Comment: Hello downvoter, care to leave a comment explaining what's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Dean's answer is about as good as it gets. Most people make use of Visual SourceSafe or Visual Studio Team Foundation Server, which fully integrates with the Visual Studio environment and is able to automatically pick out the essential files.

But people who want to make use of some other VCS do ask, and sometime get a good answer:

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3645669/Files-in-a-VB-NET-project-to-put-under-Version-con.aspx

http://www.visualstudiodev.com/visual-basic-express-edition/which-files-directories-do-i-need-to-commit-to-version-control-cvs-71894.shtml

This one's about Visual SourceSafe (now regarded as obsolete):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972977.aspx